# where column.a is not null unless column.b = value

Tags: sql, teradata

I've got a query that is pulling some data. Here is my `WHERE` clause.

```
where p.invc_dt  BETWEEN 1150101 AND 1160131    
and o.Tracking_num is not null
```

This table contains order data, and an `ORDER_CD` column to identify what type of sale or if it was refund. Refund **does not** have a tracking number associated. How can I adjust my where statement to say something like

```
and o.Tracking_num is not null **unless** `ORDER_CD` is REFUND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where p.invc_dt  BETWEEN 1150101 AND 1160131    
and ( o.Tracking_num is not null OR `ORDER_CD` = 'REFUND' )
```

Comment: `is REFUND`? Good luck with that

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the logic using boolean logic:

```
where p.invc_dt  BETWEEN 1150101 AND 1160131 and
      (o.Tracking_num is not null or order_cde = 'REFUND')
```

I'm not sure if the "unless" is meant to be exclusive, so you might mean:

```
where p.invc_dt  BETWEEN 1150101 AND 1160131 and
      ((o.Tracking_num is not null and order_cde <> 'REFUND')
       (o.Tracking_num is null and order_cde = 'REFUND')
      )
```